# AVL tree rotating techniques?

Tags: algorithm

can anyone explain rotating techniques in AVL tree and with example and there are 4 types rotates LL,RR,LR and RL.
         I know the rotating of LL and RR but i have some problem with rotating of RL and LR?

Answer (score 2):

These kind of questions really shouldn't be asked here because you can solve this with a simple google search and exploring yourself like I just did. But here is a really good way of writing the pseudo code for it:

```
IF tree is right heavy {

  IF tree's right subtree is left heavy {
     Perform Double Left rotation

  } ELSE {
     Perform Single Left rotation
  }

} ELSE IF tree is left heavy {

  IF tree's left subtree is right heavy {
     Perform Double Right rotation
  }

  ELSE {
     Perform Single Right rotation
  }
}
```

Here is the link to where I got this from. The paper also has a much more detailed explanation that should clear it up: http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~nemo/cop3530/AVL-Tree-Rotations.pdf